# Limit Rotation for bones

Tags: bones

I am trying to learn the proper way to use limit rotations for bones in my character. I have a good mesh and I have the bones inside but I cant seem to get the limits right. Please help me

Comment: You might want to be more specific. What is wrong with the limits? I would guess, you have got the convert option set wrong, try that.